# Add condition to timestamp in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to add conditions to the renaming of the batch file.

**For Example:**

- If my file is `schmrd.zip` and if the time is between 1:00 to 1.05 then it should rename as `schmrd20190205_0100`
- Similar for 1.06 to 1.25 `schmrd20190205_0120`
- And 1.26 to 1.45 `schmrd20190205_0140`

and i want it for all 24 hrs there will be 72 files each hour 3 files

**Code:**

```
::BATCH FILE
@echo off
cd C:\Users\rwaykole\Desktop\Batch
copy "SRMTSDICAPGEM.zip" Backup
move "SRMTSDICAPGEM.zip" Inbox
cd Inbox
set today=%date:~4%
for %%a in ("SRMTSDICAPGEM.zip") do ren "%%~a" "%%~na_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.zip" 

::END BATCH
```

I am unable to add these conditions. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following for loop will only take and modify the minute value, however not sure however what you want to do with times **hh:46 -> hh:59**, ahyhow, there is your full script:

```
@echo off
set mytime=%time: =0%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ("%mytime:~0,5%") do (
    set "hourval=%%a"
    if %%b geq 00 If %%b lss 06 set "minval=00"
    if %%b geq 06 If %%b lss 26 set "minval=20"
    if %%b geq 26 If %%b lss 46 set "minval=40"
)

cd /d C:\Users\rwaykole\Desktop\Batch
copy "SRMTSDICAPGEM.zip" Backup
move "SRMTSDICAPGEM.zip" Inbox
cd Inbox
set today=%date:~4%
for %%a in ("SRMTSDICAPGEM.zip") do ren "%%~a" "%%~na_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hourval%%minval%.zip"
```

Comment: i will have to add this if for every hour ?is there i way using for ill get it for each hour? by using a for loop or something cause i have 72 files 3 files for each hour

Comment: It is giving a space between hourval and minval

Comment: sorry, my bad, had additional spaces in code after `set hourval=%%a  `, copy code as is and try again.